# ¿Por que al limpiar un formulario obtengo un error 500?

Tags: nodejs, angular, formularios, express, form-submit

tengo un botón para limpiar un formulario, pero al darle click, hace al parecer una petición y el servidor me devuelve que unos campos son requeridos. En el esquema de la bd tengo que esos campos deben ser requeridos, pero igual no entiendo porque al limpiar surge el error.

```
    resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form) {
      form.resetForm()
      this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = new Employee();
    }
  }
```

Este es una parte de mi controlador, es como si ese boton llamara a createEmployee

```
employeController.createEmployee = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const Employee = new model_employee({
      name: req.body.name,
      position: req.body.position,
      officine: req.body.officine,
      salary: req.body.salary,
    });
    const resultado = await Employee.save();
    res.json({
      resultado: resultado,
      status: "Employee save",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: puedes poner el código de tu botón y dónde asocias los métodos del click? Me da la sensación de que el botón que has puesto tiene el `type="submit"` por lo que siempre ejecutará el envío del formulario

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Sí, tienes razón, se me paso por alto ese error pequeño, lo tenía como `type="subtmit"`

Comment: Me alegro!!! encantado de haberte ayudado!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los botones con el atributo `type="submit"` tienen como acción principal el envío del formulario en el que están contenidos.

Revisa si tu botón tiene esta pinta:

```
<button type="submit">Limpiar Formulario</button>
```

Si es el caso, el botón estará llamando al envío del formulario siempre.

Así debería funcionarte (no asocio al método `resetForm` el botón, porque entiendo que tú lo tendrás correctamente asociado)

```
<button>Limpiar Formulario</button>
```

Puedes evitar dicho comportamiento inicial, también con [`event.preventDefault();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58777346/3617531)  de tal modo que antes del envío, podrás modificar los valores.

Luego, [puedes enviar más tarde el contenido sin problema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050860/3617531)

[Documentación sobre submit buttons aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_submit.asp)